# ¿cómo graficar señales singulares en Python?

Tags: python, gráficas

Quiero graficar las señales:

1. escalón u(t)
2. rampa tu(t)
3. impulso
4. parabola

Y tal vez combinarlas.
Leí un poco acerca de la definición de las funciones rampa y el escalón en este link: [Señales escalón e impulso](http://blog.espol.edu.ec/telg1001/senales-miu-delta/)
Pero se me dificulta un poco entender entender la declaración de los datos a visualizar. Su ayuda con algún buen tutorial en donde se me facilite esto.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido, revisa [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), reformula tu pregunta, muestra lo que has intentado. Así será más fácil ayudarte.

Answer (score -1):

En el estudio de Sistemas Lineales Invariantes en el tiempo (SLI) y el procesamiento de señales, se definen dos funciones de vital importancia que son: el escalónu(x)  e impulso\delta(x) unitario.

Esta funciones, conocidas como señales singulares, son particularmente útiles en el tratamiento de SLI en el dominio de Laplace. Además, muchas funciones escritas por tramos se pueden expresar como combinaciones lineales de ellas.

Las definiciones de las funciones escalón  e impulso  unitario en los programas usados en el curso son:

Máxima:

unit_step(x)Maxima
delta(x)
iPython:

Se encuentran definidas en la librería sympy, módulo functions.special, como:

pythonHeaviside(x)
DiracDelta(x)
Sin embargo, la función escalón se puede definir usando la función piecewise() del módulo numpy (que viene por defecto), como:

def u(x): return piecewise(x,[x<0.0,x>=0.0],[0,1])python
Matlab:

heaviside(x)Matlab
delta(x)
De esta manera, usando estas definiciones podemos graficar funciones que se expresan como combinaciones de estas funciones singulares.

Comment: tomemos por ejemplo la función f(t)=2u(t+1)-3u(t)+2(t-1)u(t-1)-2(t-2)u(t-2)-u(t-2) ¿Cómo la ingresaría?

Comment: aquí está un enlace en el que te puedes apoyar... https://udeasytes.wordpress.com/ecuaciones/clases/semana-9-introduccion-a-sli-y-transformada-de-laplace/graficacion-de-senales-singulares/

Comment: Lo revisaré, gracias.